# Using a Qt library from a C program

Tags: c++, c, qt, dll

Qt is great for building applications, but once or twice I have wanted to show a nice Qt dialog from an existing application that is written in pure C.

I want to describe how to create a Qt-based shared or static library that is usable by a Qt-unaware program. To narrow down the problem, let's assume that we call a function that shows some dialogs or widgets, and does not return until all dialogs have been closed. Otherwise it can't be done without some 'cooperation' from the hosting process - it has to at least run the message pump for Qt.

In this example I will use the Windows program `rundll32.exe` to load and execute a function that shows the Qt about dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say our DLL is called `MyQtBasedDll.dll`, and it has a single exported function - `void MyEntryPoint()`.

We will run it using the command line `rundll32.exe MyQtBasedDll.dll,MyEntryPoint`. Note you need to give full paths for the exe and dll.

In order for `rundll32.exe` to load and use the program, `MyEntryPoint()` should have a C-calling convention. Additionally, we need a `QApplication` instance to do any GUI stuff, and  `rundll32.exe` will obviously not create it for us.

To create the Qt library with Qt Creator, we can choose *File->New File or Project->Libraries->C++ Library*, and the project name should be `MyQtBasedDll`.

The code of the `MyEntryPoint()` function is pretty simple:

```
extern "C"
{
__declspec(dllexport) void MyEntryPoint()
{
    if (!QApplication::instance()) {
        QApplication a(__argc, __argv);
        QMessageBox::aboutQt(0);
    } else {
        QMessageBox::aboutQt(0);
    }
}
}
```

This function can be called multiple times by the same exe, and each time a new `QApplication` object is constructed, only for the duration of the function. Note that we check for an existing instance so our DLL will work even when called by a Qt application.

Now all you need to do is substitute `QMessageBox::aboutQt(0);` with your function that does useful stuff!

Comment: was this an actual question or is SO now a blog for such things

Comment: @Brandin "Share your knowledge, Q&A style" - there's an option for that, didn't you know it? Also, in [the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) the staff says - *To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.*